# Flash in a browser to full screen

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, browser, fullscreen

How can i make my flash applications in a browser in full screen mode? I know that the stage can be put in that mode, but when i run the application in any browser this doesn't work. So, this can be done, but how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the HTML including the Flash SWF, add the following parameter to your <object> tag:

```
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
```

and the following attribute to your <embed> tag:

```
allowFullScreen="true"
```

Or, if you are using [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) (as you should be), add the allowFullscreen parameter to your embed code. See the [SWFObject documentation](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) for the various ways to this.

In your Flash/Flex file, you need to provide the user a way to initiate fullscreen mode - **you cannot force fullscreen without the user initiating it**. Whatever you have the user do, include this code as a response to it:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN; //Flash
systemManager.stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN; // Flex
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe it is a simple actionscript command. [Source](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary372.html)

```
 fscommand( "fullscreen" ,  "true" )
```