# Full screen mode not allowed with StageDisplayState

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, fullscreen

There is a parent Flex application that allows you to embed custom tools in it (SWF files).

I have inspected the HTML wrapper for the parent and it uses SWFObject, and has full screen permitted:

```
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
```

I am trying to put together a tool that simply takes the parent application to & from full screen mode.

[image]

Here is a simplified version of the code.  I have [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178669/flash-in-a-browser-to-full-screen) [several](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/03/15/creating-full-screen-flex-applications-in-flex-gumbo-swfobject-edition/) [variations](http://permadi.com/tutorial/flash9FullScreen/index.html), but still had no luck.

```
public function toogleScreen():void
{
 // this is fired from a function within the child swf
  if (this.stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN)
   this.stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
 else
   this.stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
}
```

Stepping through the code identifies the issue:

```
SecurityError: Error #2152: Full screen mode is not allowed.
at flash.display::Stage/set_displayState()
at flash.display::Stage/set displayState()
at ExampleCustomTools.FullScreen::fullscreen/toogleScreen()[C:\Users\Simon\Adobe Flash Builder 4\DekhoSimulator_Viewshed\src\ExampleCustomTools\FullScreen\fullscreen.mxml:53]
at ExampleCustomTools.FullScreen::fullscreen/init()[C:\Users\Simon\Adobe Flash Builder 4\DekhoSimulator_Viewshed\src\ExampleCustomTools\FullScreen\fullscreen.mxml:40]
at ExampleCustomTools.FullScreen::fullscreen/___fullscreen_Module1_creationComplete()[C:\Users\Simon\Adobe Flash Builder 4\DekhoSimulator_Viewshed\src\ExampleCustomTools\FullScreen\fullscreen.mxml:7]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:12977]
at mx.core::UIComponent/set initialized()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:1757]
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:819]
at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\hero_private_beta\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1157]
```

What am I missing here?  I imagine it maybe related to it being a separate swf to the main parent swf?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Flash player, you can only make the application full screen in response to a mouse click. Your function, `toogleScreen`, is not a mouse event handler.

Comment: I was unaware of this.  Any idea then on how to avoid a 2nd click?  The 1st click GETs the child SWF.

Comment: Indeed this is very true. Imagine what a horrible thing flash would be for the internet if you clicked on the wrong link and BAM you've got a full-screen takover for some dirty porn site. Yikes.

Comment: Understood.  I assume then this limitation means that with the confines on how this application works, I will not be able to do a full screen mode with one mouse click (i.e. 1st click fires swf to launch, and no way to then trigger another mouse click without clicking).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
function toogleScreen():void
{    
 if(stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE || stage.displayState==StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN)    
   {
      stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
   }
   else
   {
      stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
   }
}
```